# GWT and WebSocket / Push data from server to GWT client

Tags: gwt, websocket, comet

Is there any good library which supports WebSockets and is compatible with GWT? Ideally, the library would support WebSockets as well as a fallback for browsers which don't support WebSocket, e.g. a comet-like approach or polling.

I'm currently using [GWT-Comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/) to push data from my server to my GWT web application. However, this library is a bit broken in some aspects and it seems it's not maintained actively anymore. Thus, I'm searching for an alternative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), which suits the needs stated in the question pretty good. It supports GWT, and also Websockets. Also, it supports many different application Servers, like Tomcat and Jetty.