# GWT Websockets with Elemental

Tags: gwt, websocket, gwt-elemental

I would like to use websockets technology in a GWT web application.

I know that there are some implementations using Commet and Atmospere, but i would like to avoid them as they are actually a long lived HTTP request to the server.

I have my own implementation of web sockets and i would like to know if someone knows a client side library or way that i can achieve to communicate between my client/server with websockets. More specifically, i heard that GWT **Elemental** package provides this kind of functionality. I researched (googled) about that but couldn't find anything specific.

Could someone point me to the right direction? Any suggestions except **GWT Elemental** are welcomed as well.

EDIT:
I found out the below link, which is GWT-Elemental interface. I can see that it is a ReleaseCandidate version, but i would be willing to try using the functionality. So if anyone has used that before i would like to know his/her comments/suggestions.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-elemental/2.5.1-rc1/elemental/html/WebSocket.java?av=f

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218548/gwt-and-websocket-push-data-from-server-to-gwt-client

Comment: Hi @Baadshah i read this post, but it was not quite helpful for me, as i am looking something different than Commet or Atmosphere. Particularly, i would like to know the possibility of solving my problem using the GWT Elemental package, as i describe above.

Answer (score 1):

Well I haven't used `Websockets` from `Elemental` but the `FileReader` API and it worked fine.
However you have to take into account that `Elemental` is highly experimental. 
Some of the specifications in the IDL of Webkit have changed since the `Elemental` library was auto-generated and thus won't work.
So you might need to find workarounds, etc.

Working with `Elemental` is quite straightforward.
You usually use `Browser` or `Window` from the package to get an instance of the class you want to work with. 
Something like this:

```
Window window = Browser.getWindow();
WebSocket webSocket =  window.newWebSocket(URL);
webSocket.setOnmessage(new EventListener() ....);
websocket.send();
```